# Bring back and previous commit in git with out re-writing history

Tags: git, git-branch

Suppose I'm working on a branch 'devel' and I want to bring back the state of 'devel' from a few commits back with out overwriting the commits inbetween. Can anyone help me out with a relatively simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always `git checkout` a previous commit to get the commit state into your working copy. Then commit that back to the repo. Something like `git checkout <sha> -- .` from the root of your repo should do it. This syntax does not update `HEAD`, only your index and working copy.

Comment: But once I check out the precious commit I'm on a different branch. How do I get that work back to the original branch?

Comment: See my edit for the correct version of `checkout` for what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You can do `git checkout -b newbranch commit`, i.e., `git commit -b new HEAD~5` (or ask `gitk` for the commit's SHA2). Thus you start a new branch at the point given.

Note that just `git checkout commit` leaves you in "detached head" state, you are positioned at the commit, but it is floating in space, unconnected. Changes done in this state aren't integrated into the repository.

Comment: From the git-checkout man page: 'Updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index or the specified tree. If no paths are given, git checkout will also update HEAD to set the specified branch as the current branch.' So you will only end up detached if you don't include a path as I did in my example